# How to fix this compiling error?

Tags: command-line, apache2, compiling

How do I fix this compiling error in Ubuntu 18.04?

```
(weewoo)adam98832@localhost:~$ cd Cockatrice
(weewoo)adam98832@localhost:~/Cockatrice$ mkdir build
(weewoo)adam98832@localhost:~/Cockatrice$ cd build
(weewoo)adam98832@localhost:~/Cockatrice/build$ cmake . . -DWITH_SERVER=1
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/adam98832/Cockatrice/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Comment: Run your cmake command from ~/Cockatrice as there is no reason to create a build directory

Comment: Except for the typo error in line 4 that's what is says to do in the README.md file, so it's more convenient to do it that way.

Comment: A combo of that and the other answer is what worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a space between the two "dots".
Try

```
cmake .. -DWITH_SERVER=1
```

within the build dir.